# No-drop cursor doesn't appear on Mac

Tags: html, macos, safari, drag-and-drop

I recently developed drag and drop using native HTML5 apis. The drop effect applied/allowed was set to 'Move'. In windows machines, it works flawlessly where the moment I am on droppable area, the cursor is of type move and when I go to a non-droppable area, the cursor changes to no drop (the circular one with a slanted line).
However, when in macs (safari, chrome in mac etc), the no-drop cursor wont appear. The cursor remains the same no matter where it is. The functionality still works fine.

So questions - 
What I am missing in terms of setting no-drop cursor?
Does mac supports 'no-drop' or similar cursorts?